# Php Int64/Long to bits and Edit parts of the bits

Tags: php, binary

I am struggling with solving the problem of converting a long(Int64) to bits and modifiying content of it.

As an small example I've got the Long value **539624498** and the bit value of it should be **100000001010100000010000110010**.

Already there is a small problem for me I need to append the missing "0" to the front of the bits to have it to be a 64bit bitstring.

The next thing is that I want to read specific parts of it for example from the first value of the 64bit bitstring to the 10th index of the bitstring and return the value as a decimal.

That would already be great just to look at the values but since I want to do something with these values I want to modify it as a decimal but only at maximum to the value of here 10 bitstring values which would be in decimal 1024. After that it should turn the new value of that part as a bitstring and modify the part of the base bitstring which was 64bits long.

I really hope my english is at an undestandable level since I am still a student.

Comment: What's wrong with performing bitwise operations as taught in Programming 101?

Comment: I haven't worked with any bitwise operations and also the problem is that I lack experience it php to even use them correctly if I would have any experience with them in the other programming languages I do perform.

Answer (score 0):

This should take care of the leading zeros issue:

```
echo sprintf("%031b", $decimanNumber);
```

Comment: `echo sprintf()` is an "antipattern". There is absolutely no reason that anyone should ever write `echo sprintf()` -- it should be `printf()` without `echo` every time.